# Custom status Byobu

Tags: scripts, byobu, sed

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "$(byobu ls|grep attached)"|sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

this is my script in `~/.byobu/bin/`
refresh time is 1 second.

This shows the session name as the custom status,but it does so for all but 1 session.In place of showing the session name it shows ]0 for that session.

Is it some issue with the echo command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem  can be found  when you do Byobu `ls |grep` attached >> `~/byobu_out`.

When you cat this file the output is normal i.e

```
session1name:details 
session2name:details
```

but when you open it in `vi` then you see that the file is like this:

```
^[]0;[user@host](x.x.x.x)] - byobu^Gsession1name:details
session2name:details
```

So when you pass this output through `sed` it stops at `]0`.

To overcome this use `tail -c +x [filename]` to see the output, where `x` is the number of byte of the junk header.

Also the junk header is nothing but the title of the window of the byobu terminal.

Comment: it's me with who solved it in the end...accidentally made two accounts...any one knows how to merge them?